# ESP8266 GET Response fails with google script https

Tags: google-apps-script, arduino, get, esp8266

**Greetings to all of you,**

I am struggling many days to setup a communication between my ESP8266 and Google sheet through GAS. Already tried almost everything but seems not working again.

There are three things which I believe will make my issue clearer:

**1. I manage to get a response from other json services, but it doesnt work when I link with my google script URL**

**2. I am able to send data to google sheet (with GAS) only when I configure ESP8266 board to version 2.3.0 using ESP8266-HTPPS REQUEST code file but fails to get the response from GAS.**

**3. I am already updating the fingerprint certificate.**

Everything I am leaving open to public so you may test also the GAS manually.

What am I missing?

```
/*
THIS CODE WORKS PARTUALLY! IT CAN SEND VALUES TO SPREADSHEET BUT DOES NOT GET ANY RESPONSE!
 */

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* ssid = "########";
const char* password = "########";

const char* host = "script.google.com";
const int httpsPort = 443;

// Use web browser to view and copy
// SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate
const char* fingerprint = "DC 93 18 4D 42 06 17 7B D3 23 B1 BB 32 CE D4 D0 45 67 EB 10";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Use WiFiClientSecure class to create TLS connection
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  if (!client.connect(host, httpsPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) {
    Serial.println("certificate matches");
  } else {
    Serial.println("certificate doesn't match");
  }

  String url = "/macros/s/AKfycbzmdgT4ruH95PMYaXEfqP98hAoLxrElloqXWfov-dqpZ2V5z8yO/exec?tempData=5";
  Serial.print("requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);

  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  Serial.println("request sent");
  while (client.connected()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (line == "\r") {
      Serial.println("headers received");
      break;
    }
  }
  String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (line.startsWith("{\"state\":\"success\"")) {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI successfull!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI has failed");
  }
  Serial.println("reply was:");
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println(line);
  Serial.println("==========");
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}

void loop() {
}
```